# Viewing someone else's actions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to HTML5 and JavaScript, following some tutorials,
I've come up with something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Track Mouse </title>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
function main()
{
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    window.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {

        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
        // event.clientX and event.clientY contain the mouse position
        xPos = event.clientX;
        yPos = event.clientY;

        // Within entire canvas
        if (xPos >= 0 && xPos <= myCanvas.width &&
            yPos >= 0 && yPos <= myCanvas.height) {

            document.Form1.posx.value = xPos;
            document.Form1.posy.value = yPos;
            // Top-left
            if (xPos <= myCanvas.width / 2 && xPos >= 0 &&
                yPos <= myCanvas.height / 2 && yPos >= 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            // Top-right
            if (xPos <= myCanvas.width && xPos >= myCanvas.width / 2 &&
                yPos <= myCanvas.height / 2 && yPos >= 0) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
                ctx.moveTo(myCanvas.width, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            // Bottom-left
            if (xPos <= myCanvas.width && xPos >= 0 &&
                yPos <= myCanvas.height && yPos >= myCanvas.height / 2) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
                ctx.moveTo(0, myCanvas.height);
                ctx.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            // Bottom-right
            if (xPos <= myCanvas.width && xPos >= myCanvas.width / 2 &&
                yPos <= myCanvas.height && yPos >= myCanvas.height / 2) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
                ctx.moveTo(myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
                ctx.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="main()">
<form name="Form1">
POSX: <input type="text" name="posx"><br>
POSY: <input type="text" name="posy"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a demo test run of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/9YXBD/

I want to take this a step further, I want it to display someone elses movements at the same time.  So, for example, if I have two windows of Chrome open, side-by-side and make movements in the canvas of the right window, my movements will also show up in the canvas of the left window.  I looked into [server-side events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) for HTML5, but I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: Do you have a server already?

Comment: I do have a host server on HostMonster

Comment: I should clarify. Do you have a server-side web application that you want to enhance with this functionality?

Comment: I would assume so, yes.

Comment: Actually you want different clients to communicate in real time.
nodeJS may be the best solution for you. check this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3CBrCVAXTM

Comment: you should consider reading about node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without a server to connect to, which would be running a server-side application or service that provided some kind of connection hub that all clients connect to. That takes some server side programming. A browser cannot connect to another browser without some help from the outside.

You would have the server accept input from clients and then send updates to all other connected clients about what happened. Exactly how to make this will be very different depending on what server side technology you use.

What server side technology should you use? There is a near limitless away of choices here, I couldn't possibly recommend one here with any authority. Pick a language you like, and there is most likely a way to write server side code with it.

On the client side, you could use server side events to listen to updates from the server. But again your server would have to be implemented to support that protocol.

> but I just don't know where to begin.

1. You start on the server
2. Expose some API's on that server to send and receive info from clients.
3. Connect to those API's from your client (the client side JavaScript)

Comment: Others above have mentioned using Node.js above, is this what would be used for server-side applications?

Comment: Sure. But like I said there are so many of options to choose from. And you can do a task like this with all of them. But yes, node.js will allow you to create a server application that can achieve this goal.

Comment: Alright, I'll check it out.  Thanks everybody (Alex Wayne, Nephelococcygia, ProllyGeek), I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look into a technology like signalR and producing a web server application. There is a nice demo not too dissimilar to what you're doing here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr-20